# How to capture the exception and message key when using ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 to handle exceptions during deserialization

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and spring-kafka 2.2.8.RELEASE.And I'm using @KafkaListener annotation to create a consumer and I'm using all default settings for the consumer.And I'm using below configuration as specified in the Spring-Kafka documentation.

```
// other props
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, AvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
```

Now, My requirements are when there is a deserialization exception. Please suggest how can i do this.

1. Capture the exception and the record key to log the details
2. Send this record to DLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, configured with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` to the container.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek-to-current) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#dead-letters).

Deserialization exceptions are treated as fatal and will not be retried.

If you want to write your own error handler for some reason, the code in the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` shows how the exception information is extracted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try this.