# How can i capture record key and value when there is a DeserializationException while consuming a message from kafka topic?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and spring-kafka 2.2.8.RELEASE.And I'm using @KafkaListener annotation to create a consumer and I'm using all default settings for the consumer.And I'm using below configuration as specified in the Spring-Kafka documentation.

```
// other props
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, AvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
```

Now, I've implemented my custom SeekToCurrentErrorHandler by extending SeekToCurrentErrorHandler as per the below thread but the record value is coming as null and the record key is not in a readable format. Please suggest me how can i get the record key and value?

[How to capture the exception and message key when using ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 to handle exceptions during deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60553310/how-to-capture-the-exception-and-message-key-when-using-errorhandlingdeserialize)

Here is my custom SeekToCurrentErrorHandler code

```
@Component
public class MySeekToCurrentErrorHandler extends SeekToCurrentErrorHandler {

    private final MyDeadLetterRecoverer deadLetterRecoverer;

    @Autowired
    public MySeekToCurrentErrorHandler(MyDeadLetterRecoverer deadLetterRecoverer) {
        super(-1);
        this.deadLetterRecoverer = deadLetterRecoverer;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> data, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
        if (thrownException instanceof DeserializationException) {
            //Improve to support multiple records
            DeserializationException deserializationException = (DeserializationException) thrownException;
            deadLetterRecoverer.accept(data.get(0), deserializationException);
            
            ConsumerRecord<?, ?>. consumerRecord = data.get(0);
            sout(consumerRecord.key());
            sout(consumerRecord.value());
        } else {
            //Calling super method to let the 'SeekToCurrentErrorHandler' do what it is actually designed for
            super.handle(thrownException, data, consumer, container);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the key fails deserialization, the original `byte[]` can be obtained by calling `getData()` on the exception.

Similarly, if the value fails deserialization, use `getData()` to get the original data.

The `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` does this ([since 2.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/988)).

You can tell which of the key or value failed by calling `isKey()` on the exception.

**EDIT**

I was wrong, the key and value are available if the value or key failed.

This is written with Boot 2.3.4:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>(pf.getConfigurationProperties());
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
        ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> bytesPF = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs);
        KafkaOperations<byte[], byte[]> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(bytesPF);
        return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template),
                new FixedBackOff(1000, 5));
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so64597061", topics = "so64597061",
            properties = {
                    ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG
                            + ":org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer",
                    ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG
                            + ":org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer",
                    ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS
                            + ":com.example.demo.Application$FailSometimesDeserializer",
                    ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS
                            + ":com.example.demo.Application$FailSometimesDeserializer"
            })
    public void listen(String val, @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key) {
        System.out.println(key + ":" + val);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so64597061.dlt", topics = "so64597061.DLT",
            properties = {
                    ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG
                            + ":org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
                    ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG
                            + ":org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer"
            })
    public void dltListen(byte[] val, @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, required = false) byte[] key) {
        String keyStr = key != null ? new String(key) : null;
        String valStr = val != null ? new String(val) : null;
        System.out.println("DLT:" + keyStr + ":" + valStr);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so64597061", "foo", "bar");
            template.send("so64597061", "fail", "keyFailed");
            template.send("so64597061", "valueFailed", "fail");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so64597061").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic dlt() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so64597061.DLT").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    public static class FailSometimesDeserializer implements Deserializer<byte[]> {

        @Override
        public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
            String string = new String(data);
            if ("fail".equals(string)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("fail");
            }
            return data;
        }

    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

```
foo:bar
DLT:fail:keyFailed
DLT:valueFailed:fail
```

Comment: Note that starting with spring-kafka-2.3 (Boot 2.2), the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` will automatically extract the failed key/value when publishing to the DLT.

Comment: I was wrong about the key/value not being available when the other failed. See the update.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the explanation, here I've a question - if I've to capture the key and value in the handle method of my custom SeekToCurrentErrorHandler, how do i do that?

Comment: Look at how the [current `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` does it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/a6ee4b37d0a387a035739ba85fd1ede7452f2d9e/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java#L198-L228).